# Undefined value in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send an Email to the logged user in ASP MVC.

In order to pass the value from the view to the controller, I used JQuery via method "POST".

the problem that the value of Email is always "**Undefined**"

View :

```
 <tr style="font-style:oblique;font-size:16px; font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; font-weight: 600;">
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                </td>
  </tr>
```

```
<script>
    var SendEmail = function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Bestellung/SendMailToUser",
            data: { Email: $('#Email').val() },
            success: function (data) {
                alert ("Success")

            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult SendMailToUser(string Email)
    {
        string em = Convert.ToString(Email);
        bool result = false;
        result = SendEmail(em, "Delivery Email Test", " <p> This a test by Delivery !</p>");
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
    public bool SendEmail(string toEmail, string subject, string emailBody)
    {
        try
        {
            string senderEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderEmail"].ToString();
            string senderPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderPassword"].ToString();

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 100000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword);
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(senderEmail, toEmail, subject, emailBody);

            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
            client.Send(mailMessage);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157481/discussion-on-question-by-exact-undefined-value-in-jquery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the HTML you're showing, you don't *have* a form element from which to get this value:

```
$('#Email').val()
```

Which is why it's `undefined`.  Though, based on extensive comments on the question above, you don't actually *want* that form element.  Instead of asking the user to input their email address, you want to use the email address that you *already have* for that user.

In that case, remove the data element entirely:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Bestellung/SendMailToUser",
    success: function (data) {
        alert ("Success")
    }
});
```

And remove it from the server-side action method signature:

```
public JsonResult SendMailToUser()
{
    //...
}
```

Since you already know the user's email address, you just need to get *that* email address server-side.  So the question is...

> Where do you store the logged-in user's email address?

If it's their username, then you should be able to get it directly in the controller from their identity.  Putting strict dependency management aside for a moment, controllers have a `User` object you can reference:

```
var email = User.Identity.Name;
```

If it's not their username, or otherwise not part of their identity, then where is it?  Is it in your database?  In that case you would use a unique identifier for your user (still `User.Identity.Name`) to query your database to get the email address, using whatever technology/methodology you use to query your database.

Comment: I resolve it, I add this in my Controller and it works :
 connection();
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Email from Bestellung where BestellungId=(Select MAX(BestellungId) From Bestellung)", con);
                string em = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                con.Close();

Comment: @Exact: As mentioned in the comments on the question, and worth mentioning here for future readers... Your approach is a race condition waiting to happen.  That is *not* a reliable method for getting data from the database.  Track actual identifiers, don't just assume that the "most recent record" is the one you want.

Comment: yes I can only say for the futur reader that this solution works but it is not reliable and in some cases could take us to a wrong way.
I will try to find a perfect method and post it here